# A shell script initiated by Python's os.system fails to run, but the script do run when called from terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, shell

I have a Python3 script that needs to call a shell script with some parameters. When I call this shell script directly form the terminal - it works. The shell script call from terminal:

```
source $HW/scripts/gen.sh -top $TOP -proj opy_fem -clean
```

But when I try to call the shell script exactly the same way from Python 3 using os.system (or os.popen - same result), the shell script fails to run. Python call to the shell script:

```
os.system("source $HW/scripts/gen.sh -top $TOP -proj opy_fem -clean")
```

Get the next errors:

```
/project/users/alona/top_fabric_verif_env/logic/hw/scripts/gen.sh: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/project/users/alona/top_fabric_verif_env/logic/hw/scripts/gen.sh: line 18: `foreach i ( $* )'
```

Could you please shed light on why the same shell script fails to run from Python?
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach` is a C-shell command. `csh` (and derivates like `tcsh`) are not standard system shells in Unix/Linux.

If you need to use a specific shell, for instance the C-shell:

```
os.system('/bin/csh -c "put the command here"')
```

This will execute the `/bin/csh` in the standard shell, but starting two shells instead of one creates an additional overhead. A better solution is:

```
subprocess.run(['/bin/csh', '-c', 'put the command here'])
```

Note that using the shell's `source ...` command does not make much sense when the shell exits after the command.